# extJS4 difference between Ext.Ajax and Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, coldfusion

I am new to the extJS framework and after looking at these two classes I am curious when it is better to use one or the other. Is one better for submitting and one for getting? In my current situation I am using a grid and the api says to use the proxy.Ajax which I trust. But lets say I want to send the JSON back to a database, would I be better off using Ext.Ajax?

Also I am rather new to JSON I understand that its just a string with regular expressions essentially. What is the best way to send the json straight to a database if I don’t want to store the json locally?

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ext.Ajax` is used to make one-off requests to a server. You can use this for GET and POST requests.

`Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` is used by the data package, in particular, `Ext.data.Store`'s. You cannot use this 'manually'. You must use it via the data package.

Comment: can I POST with `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` ?

Comment: You can, but only when using a Ext.data.Store (saving records).